# Make77 error while installing Darknet on Windows

Tags: yolo, darknet

I am facing the Make77 problem. Can somebody help me out?

```
mingw32-make
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast obj/captcha.o obj/lsd.o obj/super.o obj/art.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/rnn.o obj/segmenter.o obj/regressor.o obj/classifier.o obj/coco.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/nightmare.o obj/instance-segmenter.o obj/darknet.o libdarknet.a -o darknet -lm -pthread  libdarknet.a
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj/go.o:go.c:(.text+0x329f): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj/go.o:go.c:(.text+0x32e1): undefined reference to `select@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
mingw32-make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Comment: same error here. Did you fix this?

Comment: Was not able to fix the error

Comment: Are you trying to compile this repo https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet ?

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoes a few weeks ago and managed to fix that.

I am confident, you are trying to compile the [original repository of Darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) on a Windows machine.

**Cause**

Unfortunately, one of the libraries used in `go.c` is *nix-only. It has a counterpart in Windows called `winsock.h`, but apparently it is not enough and the problem still persists.

**Solution**

Instead what you should do is use [another repo of Darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) which is ported to Windows properly and has a lot of support. It has exactly the same functionality as the original repo except for very little changes which only makes the framework better. Instead of compiling with `make` command, you should build it with Microsoft Visual Studio. You may go with the latest version of MVS. If you want to use a GPU and install correctly, make sure you follow the instructions here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#requirements . To avoid any weird errors, install the requirements in order.

When all requirements are installed, navigate to `build/darknet` and open darknet.sln. Switch to `Release` and `x64` and build the project.

That should be it. If you have any issues, let me know so I can help you. Also, if this solution works for you, make sure to mark my reply as the best answer.